# Why can't I call the private paint methods in the public landing gear method?

Tags: java

This is the code used to call the methods:

```
    public void landingGearConditions(MouseEvent event)
                {
                  if (event.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1)
                    System.out.println("landing gear activated");
                    paintGears();
                  if (event.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3)
                    System.out.println("landing gear retracted");
                    paintRetractedGears();
            }
```

This is the code used to paint the front and back tires:

```
    private void paintGears(Graphics page)
      {
        super.paintComponent(page);
         page.setColor(Color.black);  //set color for the tires

        page.fillOval(planex+126,planey+75,16,16); //front tire
        page.fillOval(planex+275,planey+79,16,16); //back tire
      }

      private void paintRetractedGears(Graphics page)
      {
        super.paintComponent(page);
         page.setColor(Color.blue);  //set color for the tires

        page.fillOval(planex+126,planey+75,16,16); //front tire
        page.fillOval(planex+275,planey+79,16,16); //back tire
      }
```

What is the meaning of the error, "The method paintRetractedGears(java.awt.Graphics) in the type Plane2 is not applicable for the arguments ()"

Comment: paintRetractedGears(); is defined to accept certain arguments which you aren't providing ... I think it accepts an instance of type java.awt.Graphics

Comment: The method expects a `Graphics` object as a parameter, but you don't provide it when calling it.

Comment: All these questions have the same reason: the defined method signature doesn't match the one you are trying to use when calling the method. Its like entering a restaurant and ordering menu 3, the one with tomato soup. And then the waiter telling you: "I dont understand,  menu 3 doesn't come with tomato soup?"